# Deleting element from JSON is leaving me an undefined element

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON Object, that i need to loop through and delete some elements. However after I delete an element I end up with an undefined element instead, this is causing me issues, as I am unable to use this "new JSON" (I am trying to use it within datatables)

the following is what I am currently doing

```
    function dTable(presId){
  var allregos = '[{"presId": "a09N0000004UbBnIAK","name": "Something","id": "001N000000Mw7knIAB"},{"presId": "a09N0000004UbBnIAK","name": "test catty","id": "001N000000O98IoIAJ"},{"presId": "a09N0000004UbBnIAK","name": "Something","id": "001N000000Mw7knIAB"}]';
  var newJson;
  var regoValue;
  for (var ke in allregos) {
    if (allregos.hasOwnProperty(ke)) {
      regoValue = allregos[ke].presId;
      if(regoValue != presId){
        delete allregos[ke];
      }else{
        //INstead of delete I could maybe create a new JSON by adding the whole node?
        //but I am unable to add the node
        //newJson = newJson.allregos[ke];
      }
    }
  } 

  console.log(allregos);
  console.log(newJson);

  j$('#myRegos').dataTable( {
      "data": newJson,
      "destroy": true,
      "columns": [
          { "title":"Name", "mData": "name", "class": "center" },
      ]
  } );
}
```

my console log shows me something like:

```
[undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, Object { presId="a09N0000004W3YLIA0", name="name 1", id="001N000000Mw7knIAB"}, Object { presId="a09N0000004W3YLIA0", name="Call Centre", id="001N000000MvDaMIAV"}, Object { presId="a09N0000004W3YLIA0", name="Who Is", id="001N000000MvIiaIAF"}]
```

is there a way to get rid of the undefiend elements?

The other work around that I was thinking was instead of deleting the elements add the appropiate ones into a new JSON however I am not able to do this. I was trying something like:

```
newJson = newJson.allregos[ke];
```

Comment: nothing is new about JSON.  There are no JSON objects. There are only numbers, strings, arrays, and objects.   JSON is merely a string, and has the format of the right hand side of an Javascript `var x = ` assignment.

Comment: This line isn't valid javascript.  `var allregos = {!customAcctRegLstTXT};`   The reason why is because `{}` is an object literal, usually containing a list of properties and values, `!` is a boolean not, and `customAcctRegLstTXT` is undefined here.  While it might be text, that line won't decode the JSON into an object.  Perhaps you are looking for `var allregos = JSON.parse(customAcctRegLstTXT); `  However, in the rest of the question you act like this works, so I am confused by the question.

Comment: `JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format[...]` and is delivered as string or buffer. What you are talking about are normal JavaScript objects and arrays but not `JSON`.

Comment: The output indicates that `allregos`  is an array. You can't remove elements from an Array using `delete anArray[index]` at least not without leaving a gap (`undefined`). To remove an element from an Array you need to use [MDN: Array.prototype.splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Hi Paul, Sorry I should be more clear, this is a visualforce page. I have edited the line to make it more clear

Comment: Hi t.niese, Thank you for the link, I read it before I post this question, however I wasnt able to use it properly/couldnt make it work. For instance how can I delete all the objects within allregos that have as a presId = "a09N0000004UbBnIAK"?

Comment: In you updated code `allregos` is just a string so `for (var ke in allregos) {` would not have the excepted effect. Beside that you would use the `Array.prototype.splice()` the at the same place where you use `delete allregos[ke]` right now. But most likely `Array.prototype.filter()` would be what you are actually looking for. Anyway you should never use `for (var ke in allregos) {` to loop over an Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we have **allRegos** as **an array of objects** so a better way to use it is to take advantage of **the standard for** without using **for (var ke in allregos)** and then 
    **if (allregos.hasOwnProperty(ke))** 
and also i'm converting the **json string** to a **real json** data by calling *JSON.parse(allregos)*
below is the enhanced dTable function 
note also that i added another object with **presId='a09N0000004UbBnIAz'** just to see if we are getting the right answer when we call the **dTable('a09N0000004UbBnIAK');**

```
function dTable(presId){
   allregos = '[{"presId": "a09N0000004UbBnIAK","name": "Something","id": "001N000000Mw7knIAB"}, {"presId": "a09N0000004UbBnIAK","name": "test catty","id": "001N000000O98IoIAJ"}, {"presId": "a09N0000004UbBnIAK","name": "Something","id": "001N000000Mw7knIAB"},{"presId": "a09N0000004UbBnIAz","name": "Something","id": "001N000000Mw7knIAB"}]'; 
   oldJson = allregos; 
   var regoValue;

allregos = JSON.parse(allregos);
oldJson = JSON.parse(oldJson);
newJson = [];



  for( i=0;i<allregos.length;i++){
    regoValue = allregos[i].presId;
    if(regoValue != presId){
        delete allregos[i];
    }else{
        newJson.push(allregos[i]);
    }
  }

  console.log('allregos before:');
  console.log(oldJson);
  console.log('allregos after:')
  console.log(allregos);
  console.log('newJson after:')
  console.log(newJson);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of the elements by completely overwriting the object.

Say you have

```
var myObject = {
"keyFoo" : "valueFoo",
"keyBar" : "valueBar",
"keyBaz" : undefined
};
```

in order to find out which values are not undefined, you can gothrough your object, and only set values which return true. In this scenario, you can isolate "keyBaz", because
(x.keyBaz) returns false when coerced into a boolean context, whereas
(x.keyFoo) and (x.KeyBar) both return true when coerced into a boolean context. You can do also do this within an array.

You can then overwrite the object by doing:

```
myObject  = {
"keyFoo" : "valueFoo",
"keyBar" : "valueBar"
};
```

Comment: What do you mean with `and only set values which return true`  and `because (x.keyBaz) is false`. for `"keyBaz" : undefined`  `x.keyBaz` is not `false`, because it is `undefined`, but a _falsy_  value.

Comment: If you put an undefined value, such as `x.keyBaz`, between parentheses, it returns `false`

For example:

`console.log((x.keyBaz));`
would result in the log `false`, and 
`console.log((x.keyFoo));` would result in the log `true`

Comment: `undefined` is still _falsy_ and not `false`. The _falsy_ it coerced to `false` when evaluated in a boolean context. This is also between parentheses `(undefined) === false` but here `undefined` is not coerced to `false`. The same with with _truthy_ values. And `console.log((x.keyBaz));` logs `undefined` and not `false`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and apologies: `console.log(!x.keyBaz)` would return in `true` and `console.log(!x.keyFoo)` would return in `false`